# Installing sql server express: VS2008 sp1 problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am trying to install SQL server express 2008 on my machine. I get an error message that says that older version of VS 2008 in installed on the computer. Upgrade to VS2008 SP1 before installing Sql server 2008.

I tried to install sp1 but I get an error message that a compatible version of vs2008 is not detected on the system. the upgrade is not compatible with express editions.

I am having trouble installing sql server 2008 express installed on my machine and I am having problems. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem that ironsavior describes. I had VS 2008 SP1 and no other VS installed (i.e. no Express edition of anything.)

[Here's how I solved](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2010/03/07/rule-quot-previous-releases-of-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-quot-failed.aspx) it, basically a registry *incentive*.
I went to the the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0\IDE\1033` and changed the following values (they used to be **0**, **0**, and **"RTM"** respectively)

```
SP = dword:00000001
SPIndex = dword:00000001
SPName = "SP1"
```

You don't even need to quit the installer to do this. Just rerun the checks after the registry tweak and it should pass. At least worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the full version of Visual Studio 2008 installed in order to upgrade to Service Pack 1. You should have a look on the MS site for an SP1 specific to the Express editions of Visual Studio.

In fact I'm not certain but try redownloading Visual Studio express and it should have SP1 already integrated. Here's a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vb/default.aspx).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't compulsory to install the full version of Visual Studio 2008 to upgrade to Service Pack 1. You can install any of the express editions with sp1, ideally Visual C++ and C#. If you already have them installed on your PC, re-install and remove any old versions of SQL Server Express(2000 or 2005 in Add/Remove Programs). Finally, install SQL Server 2008 Express; this should solve the problem.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Express SP1 updater doesnt work on SQL Express, believe it or not.   If you patch SQL Express using the "full version of sql 2008 sp1", that will work.  I found this to be the case in June of 2009.